# How to share your github account on your blog?

Tags: github

I know that Stack Overflow has a short script like Facebook, LinkedIn etc. to share your account details on your website or your blog. Even if I looked at it on google and stack overflow, I could not find anything like that. Do you know such script for GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best available option is the [Github badge](http://githubbadge.appspot.com/).

Github unfortunately does not provide their own version of an embeddable badge; you can try requesting one [through support](https://github.com/contact).

Comment: Ok, so there is no such a thing that github provides?

Comment: Nope, nothing provided by Github unfortunately!

Answer (score 2):

There are also [GitHub Buttons.](http://ghbtns.com/)

But these are not created by GitHub itself....